# Why I have two /dev/sdx entries with a single disk?

Tags: devices, block-device, ssd, disk

In my laptop (running Linux) I have only one SSD, connected to the SATA3 port.

Why I have two **sdx** entries  in `/dev` directory?

In particular I see `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, and `/dev/sda` is the SSD:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x00034e4b

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   125954047    62976000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       125954048   190466047    32256000   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       190466048   222210047    15872000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       222210048   250068991    13929472    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational 
0
```

The surprising thing is the following:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational 
1
```

So it looks like that `/dev/sdb` is considered as a magnetic hard disk drive.

What's the point?

EDIT:

```
# lshw -C disk
  *-disk                  
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: xD/SD/M.S.
       vendor: Generic-
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 1.00
       serial: 3
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdb
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: SAMSUNG SSD 830
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: CXM0
       serial: S0Z3NSAC905663
       size: 119GiB (128GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=00034e4b
```

Comment: It seems the kernel does detect a block device. Please provide the output of `lshw -C disk` (as root).

Comment: @gertvdijk Edited first post. So I have an empty SCSI port on my laptop?

Comment: No, it's not empty - it's your card reader. What kernel version are you on? And what type of laptop are you on?

Comment: Kernel 3.6, my laptop is a ThinkPad Edge E130 and yes, it has a card reader. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the update (`lshw …` output) there is the answer now:

`product: xD/SD/M.S.`

That's your laptop's cardreader. Also, `capabilities: removable`.

*UPDATE*:
As for the mentioned `/sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational` value being `1`, this parameter actually influences the I/O scheduling algorithm in Linux. Probably, it should have been named something like 'minimize-seek' or similar, because this is what it is intended to do.

I'm not sure why it has been set to `1` for your particular device, I'm not that good in the flash memory architecture and technologies. But I can easily imagine an implementation that works better when accessing adjacent memory units first is quicker than jumping here and there over the medium (roughly equivalent to seeking).

Comment: I've seen `capabilities: removable` also appear on AHCI-enabled, hotswap-aware controllers/drives too.

Comment: Agreed, that's not a distinctive feature of a floppy drive/CD-DVD reader/cardreader.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `lshw` in your updated question appears to provide the information you're looking for; it's your flash card reader. Why it would appear as a magnetic drive is unclear to me - I would say this is a bug or a firmware error to represent itself like this.